# How to do in order to use binary file for C language at Bluemix

Tags: binary, ibm-cloud

We are planning to call binary files for C language from some script languages in order to keep the programs of C language private as customer's assets.
Could you please tell us the reference materials for implementing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the "null buildpack" to directly call compiled C/C++ code (x86 linux, gcc, etc)

https://github.com/ryandotsmith/null-buildpack

Also see this - https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/17784/newbie-how-to-deploy-c-c-apps-in-blue-mix.html